# Toggle show/hide issue

Tags: javascript, html, toggle, hide, show

Hy,

I have a small problem, with the following HTML code & JS

```
<ul class="categories">
   <a href="#" class="togglelink"><li class="furniture">Furniture</li></a>  
   <a href="" class="togglelink"><li class="general-items">General</li></a>
   <a href="" class="togglelink"><li class="cars">Cars</li></a>
   <a href="" class="togglelink"><li class="moto">Moto</li></a> 
   <a href="" class="togglelink"><li class="other-vehicles">Vehicles</li></a>
   <a href="" class="togglelink"><li class="house">House</li></a>
   <a href="" class="togglelink"><li class="boat">Boats</li></a>  
   <a href="" class="togglelink"><li class="truck">Trucks</li></a>
   <a href="" class="togglelink"><li class="fragile">Fragile</li></a>
   <a href="" class="togglelink"><li class="animals">Animals</li></a>  
   <a href="" class="togglelink"><li class="others">Others</li></a>
</ul>
```

And the supposed hidden DIV content is:

```
<!-- start of furniture -->
     <div class="row">
         <div class="panel panel-default panel-custom toggle" style="display: block;">
             <div class="panel-body"> 
                <p>Furniture content</p>
             </div>
         </div>
      </div>
<!-- end of furniture -->
```

And the JS that I'm using is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
    $('.toggle').hide();
    $('a.togglelink').click(function() {
        $('.toggle').hide();
        $(this).parent().next('.toggle').toggle('slow');
        return false;
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FRde7/

Only the problem is that all the content DIVs are shown, none are hidden as suppose to be.

Any ideas why this is not working ?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to accomplish? I don't see a toggle class either unless its somewhere else, I think you mean $('.togglelink').hide(); . Here's the example: http://jsfiddle.net/54d2S/

Comment: Oh, my bad. I forgot that part!

That list is styled with icons for each category. When I click for example the moto icon, I want that the hidden div content of that category to be shown.

Comment: But you don't have a hidden `<div>` content for each of your categories. I see only Furniture Content.

Comment: I just copied just one div content, not all of them.

Comment: Give me 5 min, I'll make you a jsfiddle, to show you that I'm not.

Comment: I made a example: `http://jsfiddle.net/FRde7/

I want the div of the each category to be hidden, but when i click it, to be shown.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. `a` is not a valid child of `ul`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is flawed. You'll probably want to reference each instance of `.toggle` by the index of the `.togglelink` that's been clicked:

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/FRde7/4

```
$('.toggle').hide();

$('a.togglelink').click(function() {
    var myIndex = $(this).index();
    $('.toggle').hide();

    $('.toggle').eq(myIndex).toggle('slow');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thank you! That is what I need, and I'm sorry I did not explain myself clearly.